# how to do ftp which will not ask for username and password in shell script?

Tags: unix, ftp

I tried like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
hostname="xx.xx.xx.xx"
username="ftp"
password="123456"
ftp $username:$password@$hostname <<EOF
read filename
put $filename
quit
EOF
```

erorr is coming as below :

```
ftp: ftp:123456@10.64.40.11: Name or service not known
?Invalid command
Not connected.
```

If my question is too easy , please don't bother to answer.

I am beginner and trying to learn. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that the default FTP client doesn't allow you to specify user and password along with host at the command line like that.  It's looking for a host named `ftp:123456@10.64.40.11`, which clearly wouldn't exist.  You can specify the host at the command line, but that's it.  This situation and solution is well described in [this article](http://www.stratigery.com/scripting.ftp.html), which contains other versions and examples.

The basic idea is to turn off "auto-login" with `-n` and specify the user and password inside the HERE document instead of at the command line:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    hostname="xx.xx.xx.xx"
    username="ftp"
    password="123456"
    ftp -n $hostname <<EOF
    user $username $password
    read $filename
    put $filename
    quit
    EOF
```

(Notice that I added the `$` to `read filename`, which appeared to be a typo in your original version.)

There are other FTP clients that allow for user and password specification at the command line (such as [ncftp](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/)), but using the one you have seems the simplest option.